# How does garbage collector know a raw pointer and its referenced memory is no longer used

Tags: garbage-collection

I'm new to garbage collection, I have read this page:
[A garbage collector for C and C++](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/), it gives a simple example in the page: [Using the Garbage Collector: A simple example](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/simple_example.html).

```
    #include "gc.h"
    #include <assert.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
      int i;

      GC_INIT();    /* Optional on Linux/X86; see below.  */
      for (i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
       {
         int **p = (int **) GC_MALLOC(sizeof(int *));
         int *q = (int *) GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC(sizeof(int));
         assert(*p == 0);
         *p = (int *) GC_REALLOC(q, 2 * sizeof(int));
         if (i % 100000 == 0)
           printf("Heap size = %d\n", GC_get_heap_size());
       }
      return 0;
    }
```

Here, `*p` is a pointer in garbage collector managed memory, and it point to a memory also inside the managed memory.

I'm curious that how does the garbage collector know that the two memory allocated in a previous `for` loop is leaked and should be reclaimed in the next `for` loop.

Comment: The algorithm (well.. the basic form) is called 'Mark & Sweep'. Basically all stack frames are walked, checking all local variables and marking them during the walk (recursively). Statics are also marked using the same procedure. During the sweep phase all non-marked variables are collected. In C this is a little more complicated though, as explained on the Boehm GC page.

Comment: Ah here it is: http://www.hboehm.info/gc/gcdescr.html .

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).